# How can I solve this problem : getting values, and type error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to get values like '2'. But Board.findOne({attributes: ['deadline']}, {where : {name : boardID}}) print 'id : 2'. I want to solve this.

Moreover, I have a TYPEERROR like this.
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Sequelize'
    |     property 'dialect' -> object with constructor 'MysqlDialect'
    --- property 'sequelize' closes the circle

How can I solve this problems?

```
router.post('/create/:boardID', async (req,res,next) => {
const boardID = req.params.boardID;
try{
    const find = await Board.findOne({attributes: ['deadline']}, {where : {name : boardID}});
    const deadline = moment(find).format();
    if(moment(deadline).diff(moment().format()) < 0){
        const post = await Post.create({
            content : req.body.content,
            url : req.body.url
        });
        res.json(Object.values(find));
        const submit = await Submit.create({
            userId : req.body.userId,
            boardId : Object.values(find)
        });

        res.json(post + " : " + submit);
    } else {
        return res.json({req : false, msg : '기간이 지났습니다'});
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    next(err);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think that, you have been wrong when using `findOne`

```
const find = await Board.findOne({
   attributes: ['deadline'],
   where : {name : boardID}
});
const deadline = moment(find.deadline).format();
```

You could use to try this.